# Hidden tweaks to allow certain users make remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-sbs-2008

The set up is Windows 7 with Windows SBS 2008.

I see that ALL the clients have remote desktop access on the server, but of course I don't want that. I checked System and Maintenance settings and only the people I wanted seemed to have access. So, for some days, I disabled remote desktop connections and I access the server only by teamviewer/logmein. But this is not very practical.

Are there any other tweaks I have to do in order to achieve the desired result? Either prompt clients for admin password or block it at all.

Comment: Are the user's putting in their own user name and password, or are they just clicking on an RDP link and it takes them right in? If they just click on the shortcut, it could have the credentials already put in.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: right click on the rdp icon and go to edit. See if a user name and password is already there. If it is, that's why they can login.

Comment: That's good. I will check it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite understanding what you're seeing or how you're seeing it, but there are no hidden tweaks. If the users are able to remotely access the server then it sounds like the users have the wrong role. Do the users have the Standard User role or the Network Administrator role? It sounds like they have the Network Administrator role. Standard Users don't have remote access to the SBS server. You can change the user role for each user if needed in the SBS console.

Comment: If they are on the Network Administration team, why they are not able to install software or make changes such as edit tcp/ip properties? I think they should. That's why I cant figure out what is going on...